# Swap in shell from file

Tags: bash, shell, swap, cut

Through `cut -d":" -f1,3` I made a new file which looks like this:

```
username1:number1
username2:number2
username3:number3
```

But my point is, I want to my file to looks like this:

```
number1:username1
number2:username2
number3:username3
```

I tried that `cut -d":" -f3,1` but it still gets me `username1:number1` even when I want to be that 3rd column be the 1st and the 1st column to print it like a last one ... Any help with that ?

Comment: You need to provide exact input and out put for others to try and answer at the moment input is partial or not even there

Answer (score 4):

`cut -f3,1` will print the same as `cut -f1,3`. Use `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{print $3 FS $1}' file
```

Comment: I know I know ... Its working now ... But what FS mean in this awk ?

Comment: `FS` is the field separator, which we set to `:` with `-F:`. Similar to `cut -d":"`

Answer (score 1):

I like awk for this sort of thing. You've already got an awk answer though.

To do this in pure bash, you'd do the following:

```
while IFS=: read -r one two; do printf '%s:%s\n' "$two" "$one"; done < input.txt
```

The `IFS` variable is the field separator used to slice up the input into separate variables for `read`, and I'm using `printf` to gives us predictably formatted output.